# How to properly check if a number is a prime number

Tags: python, function

Hey so i have this function to check if a number is a prime number

```
def is_prime(n):
    flag = True
    for i in range(2, n ):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            flag = False
    return flag


print(is_prime(1))
```

However when i test the number 1, it skips the for loop and returns True which isn't correct because 1 is not a prime number.
How could i fix this?

Comment: You have to make it a special case. just return False if n == 1.

Comment: Thanks, would you happen to know why it thinks 1 is a prime number. The whole thing is a discussion in mathematics in general. Some people think 1 is not a prime number and some think the opposite.

Comment: Clearly if you start looping from 2, your current code is not well-defined for 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can first start by checking if `n` is greater than `1` the code should proceed, else it should return `False`. If `n` passes the first condition, only then the code can proceed to verify if `n` is indeed prime or not.

```py
def is_prime(n):
    flag = True
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2, n ):
            if (n % i) == 0:
                flag = False

        return flag # Returns this flag after check whether n is prime or not
        
    # Returns False if n <= 1
    return False


print(is_prime(1))
```

output:

```py
False
```

Answer (score 0):

2 is also skipped by the loop, but the function returns true thanks to the flag, and we know that's right.

Also you can exit early the loop if the condition is met:

```py
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2, n): # if n == 2, there is no loop, is never checked
            if (n % i) == 0:
                return False # can return early once we meet the condition, don't need to finish the loop

    return True

print(is_prime(7534322224))
print(is_prime(5))
```

An alternative approach (though much slower on bigger numbers):

```py
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    if n < 2: return False    
    return n == 2 or True not in [True for i in range(2, n) if (n % i) == 0]

print(is_prime(75343224))
print(is_prime(5))
```